# Dynamically Generated React Controlled Inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, drop-down-menu, combobox

I have a window where a group of 3 HTML combo box(select box) are generated on every button click.
lets say category,subcategory and data. options in sub category and data are dynamically rendered based on its previous selected value.

i am storing the selected values as an array of object like

```
 const [exerciseData, setExerciseData] = useState([[]]);
```

Sample data:

```
exerciseData : [
  //first group 
    [
      category:"",
      subcategory:"",
      name:""
    ],
    //second group
    [
      category:"",
      subcategory:"",
      name:""
    ]

]
```

So literally first group of input can be indicated by `exerciseData[0]` and next by `exerciseData[1].category` etc..

The problem is i want there groups like to be reordered by the user like moving up 1 group or moving down by 1.So i need the select boxes to be a controlled element.  But how can i set that?

I tried like this :

```
<select name="category" value={exerciseData[i].category} ... > {options} </select>
```

when i give like this the select box value cannot be changed.it always stays at its default value.

any suggestion will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'based on its previous selected value'? Based on `category` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an input controlled, you need to manually handle the input value via state. In your example, the input value seems to be fixed/static.

The following snippet is an example of how to create a controlled `select` input in React.

***Update:***

Made a full demo snippet. Please let me know if that is what you was looking for.

```js
const {useState, useCallback, Fragment} = React;

const categories = [
  {
    id: 'CAT.1',
    data: [
      {
        id: 'CAT.1 SUB.A',
        data: [
          {id: 'CAT.1 SUB.A OPT.1'},
          {id: 'CAT.1 SUB.A OPT.2'},
          {id: 'CAT.1 SUB.A OPT.3'}
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'CAT.1 SUB.B',
        data: [
          {id: 'CAT.1 SUB.B OPT.1'},
          {id: 'CAT.1 SUB.B OPT.2'},
          {id: 'CAT.1 SUB.B OPT.3'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'CAT.2',
    data: [
      {
        id: 'CAT.2 SUB.A',
        data: [
          {id: 'CAT.2 SUB.A OPT.1'},
          {id: 'CAT.2 SUB.A OPT.2'},
          {id: 'CAT.2 SUB.A OPT.3'}
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'CAT.2 SUB.B',
        data: [
          {id: 'CAT.2 SUB.B OPT.1'},
          {id: 'CAT.2 SUB.B OPT.2'},
          {id: 'CAT.2 SUB.B OPT.3'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
];

function Select(props) {
  const {
    name,
    options = [],
    onIndex
  } = props;

  const [value, setValue] = useState(options[0] && options[0].id);
  
  const onChangeHandler = useCallback((e) => {
    onIndex && onIndex(options.findIndex((item) => item.id === e.target.value));
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }, [onIndex, options]);
  
  return (
      <label>
        {name}:
        <select value={value} onChange={onChangeHandler}>
          {
            options.map((item) => {
              const {id} = item;
              return <option value={id}>{id}</option>;
            })
          }
        </select>
      </label>
    );
}

function Field() {
  const [catIndex, setCatIndex] = useState(0);
  const [subIndex, setSubIndex] = useState(0);
  
  return (
      <div>
        <Select name='Category' options={categories} onIndex={setCatIndex}/>
        <Select name='Sub Category' options={categories[catIndex].data} onIndex={setSubIndex}/>
        <Select name='Option' options={categories[catIndex].data[subIndex].data}/>
      </div>
    );
}

function App() {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState(() => [<Field />]);
  
  const addField = useCallback(() => {
    setFields((prevFields) => {
      const index = prevFields.lenght;
      return [...prevFields, <Field key={index} />];
    });
  }, []);
  
  return (
      <Fragment>
        <form>
          {fields}
        </form>
        <button type='button' onClick={addField}>Add Field</button>
      </Fragment>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Please let me know if you have any doubt.